# how to find source search for a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have a existing table called property i alter a column called overbook_percent (i change a number 2 to 3) but i want to do a source search to make sure that there is not a variable declaration that sets this to just 2 digits. how would i go about this?not sure you called this a source search. 
how can i see where this table column is use?

i tried this but get no output

```
select text
  from dba_source
where upper(text) like 'OVERBOOK_MAX'
;
```

I'm working on toad for oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you are looking for this:-

```
select owner, table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'OVERBOOK_MAX';
```

This will search all tables with a column name `OVERBOOK_MAX`

For checking in stored procedures you may try this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT type, name
FROM dba_source
WHERE owner = 'OWNER'
AND UPPER(text) LIKE '%OVERBOOK_MAX%';
```

**EDIT**

to search a string try this:-

```
SELECT owner, name, type, line, text 
FROM dba_source
WHERE instr(UPPER(text), UPPER(:search_string)) > 0;
```

Comment: That will not search for procedures or  functions using that column.

Comment: "altering table P_PM_PROPERTY to increase the existing column OVERBOOK_MAX_PERCENT from NUMBER(2) to NUMBER(3).

You will need to do a source search to find where all in the code that we reference this code to ensure that there is not a variable declaration that sets this to just 2 digits."

Comment: is there a way i can search all the code use , not just the tables?

Comment: Updated my answer!!! This will search in stored procedures as well!!! Does that help?

Comment: Will this search all the database for that specific key word?

Comment: It will serach for the Column Name in stored procedure. If you want to search for some string then its a different story. Updating my answer for that too!!

Comment: @user2744775:- Hope that is clear. And do accept this as an answer if that helped

Comment: when you do the string search does it search on code? on all the source code?